# command line from within a program - not all commands are executed issue

Tags: android, command-line

I wrote some code that runs an android command line and collect the output.

it is executing "ls" correctly but when I put the command "top -n 1" it shows nothing.

is it a manifest issue? the phone is not rooted and when using "terminal emulator" I can see "top" output.

here is the code:

```
// ** execute command line and gather the output **//
    final StringBuilder log = new StringBuilder();
    try{
        ArrayList<String> commandLine = new ArrayList<String>();
        commandLine.add("top");
        commandLine.add("-n1");

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandLine.toArray(new String[0]));

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){ 
            log.append(line);
            log.append(", \n"); 
        }
        log.append(", \n");
    } 
    catch (IOException e){

    }
```

thanks,
A.

Comment: I don't think executing command line applications is officially supported which means it's undefined whether it works or not especially across devices.

Comment: OK, I succeed to run "ps" but I am getting a lot of "root" processes. how can i trim all "root" processes. are there any suffix for PS command in order to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to show some of your code. Generally, commands you run using `Runtime` are not executed in a shell, so you might want to try something like "sh -c top -n 1" as the `prog` parameter.

Comment: Well, you might want to use the debugger to check where it's 'stuck'.